Add delay to Apache HTTP responses to push people to switch to the new server?
I have an apache server, and I want people to update their settings (domain name) to a new server, but I don't want to turn off the old server.
Is it possible to tell apache to continue to reply to http requests as normal but slower? i.e. I want to add a delay into their HTTP responses. I don't want to turn off their service, I just want to push them to change. A fixed delay for every request is acceptable, but it would be better if the delay would increase every day, so the services gets progressively “worse”.
Is this possible in Apache? Even with some third party module?
Apache 2.4 installed via apt in Ubuntu (a solution which works on Ubuntu 20.04 & 22.04 & 24.04 would be great).

Why not serve a redirect?

I will set up a HTTP Redirect. However, most software will just accept that, and the person won't have to update their software. I want them to notice something is “wrong”

You can add a delay with Lua: Force delay on apache response times
You can also set a low bandwidth rate limit with mod_ratelimit to have them suffer: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_ratelimit.html
